# Unit test fails with this.id is null when using lombok @Getter and @Setter, but works when using @Data on the Entity class

Tags: java, spring, junit, getter-setter, lombok

I am using lombok `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations on my Entity class.

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Achievements")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Achievement extends DomainObject {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Column(name = "Name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "Details")
  private String details;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "AchievementTypeId", nullable = false)
  private AchievementType achievementType;
  
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "QuestId")
  private Quest quest;
}
```

When I run the following unit test. it fails:

```java
@Test
  public void saveAchievementTest() {
    Achievement achievement = new Achievement();
    achievement.setId(UUID.fromString(achievementId));
    AchievementRequestDTO achievementRequestDTO = new AchievementRequestDTO();
    achievementRequestDTO.setAchievementTypeId(UUID.fromString(achievementTypeId));
    achievement.setAchievementType(achievementType);
    when(achievementTypeRepository.getOne(achievementRequestDTO.getAchievementTypeId()))
        .thenReturn(achievementType);
    when(achievementRepository.save(achievement)).thenReturn(achievement);
    Achievement dbAchievement = achievementService.saveAchievement(achievementRequestDTO);
    assertEquals(dbAchievement.getId(), UUID.fromString(achievementId));
  }
```

The above run fails with a `NullPointerException` stating that `dbAchievement is null`. However, the same test case works when(in either of the two cases):

1. I use `@Data` annotation instead of `@Getter` and `@Setter` in the entity class.
2. I change the when statement in the test to `when(achievementRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(achievement);`

I suppose the issue here is the comparison of hashcodes to compare the object passed. I want to stick to using `@Getter and @Setter` in my entity. What should I do differently to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your test fails because the object you save, doesn't equal the object initialized.

Lombok's `@Data` incorporates `@ToString @EqualsAndHashCode @Getter @Setter` and `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

Every Java class has a default no-args constructor if there's none specified (as you have).

When you call your test, you're calling for a `getId()` on a field that's initialized as `null`

To solve this, you can seperately add the Lombok `@AllArgsConstructor`or the `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

Comment: How does the initialization of the id happen in this case? Just adding `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to the entity doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: your problem is two-fold. The ```.thenReturn()``` is only activated if the element in the ```.when()```condition matches. Which means you have to create a corresponding dummy object. In your test ```Achievement achievement = new Achievement()```should become the creation of a full object, not an initialisation with an empty object. Running your save-method will generate a different ID in the database. Which is why it is advisable to create a variable in your class with  ```Long id``` annotated with ```@Id```

Comment: I am using a mapped super class which contains the id already

Comment: read over that the first time I answered. Inheritance with Lombok is tricky. Might I suggest you read up on the attached link? Don't hesitate to comment, I'm curious myself.  https://medium.com/consulner/lombok-tricks-and-common-mistakes-fbf0ed044c3c